# How to Compute the charge $Q$ of a particular state in free Dirac field?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, charge, dirac-equation

For a free Dirac field, how can I explicitly compute the charge $Q$ of the state $a_{p1}^{r \dagger}a_{p2}^{s \dagger} b_{p3}^{t \dagger}|0>$.

The operator $Q$ is :
\begin{equation}
Q = \int \frac{d^3 p}{(2 \pi)^3} \Sigma_s \bigg(a_p^{s \dagger}a_p^s-b_p^ {s \dagger} b_p^s \bigg)
\end{equation}

Comment: If your state is $|\psi\rangle$, then you just need to compute $\langle\psi|Q|\psi\rangle$. It will involve lots of commutations for your case.